# Get values form 2 columns in for each loop Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach

I am trying to build a function using google apps script to loop through the below table and send an email to each supplier with the correct items to order.

My to order range looks like this:

```
 Supplier Name  |   Item                | Qty
-----------------------------------------------------
My Veg Supplier |   Baby Spinach (Kg)   |0.8
My Veg Supplier |   Basil (Kg)          |0.1
My Veg Supplier |   Chives (KG)         |0.2
My Veg Supplier |   Lettuce Mixed       |1
My Veg Supplier |   Onions Spring       |3
Baking Supplier |   Apple Cruffin       |3
Baking Supplier |   Brioche Rolls       |7
Baking Supplier |   Croissant Plain     |17
Baking Supplier |   Dinner Roll         |6
Baking Supplier |   RSofa Ciabatta      |5
Baking Supplier |   Seed Loaf Large     |1
```

and my supplier info range looks like this:

```
Supplier Name   |   Email           
-------------------------------------------------
My Veg Supplier |   veg@veg.com 
Baking Supplier |   bread@bread.com
```

I have a script that loops through trough and correctly gets the items to order, as well as loops through the supplier info range and for each value gets the associated email address.

I'll leave out the first function that gets the items to order as its quite long and isn't the problem, but I am battling to say "loop through suppliers and get the supplier name AND email address for mailApp.sendEmail etc"

My current function gets each supplier and sends a mail successfully, but always sends to all addresses for all suppliers instead of just the address associated with that supplier

Here it is:

```
  function loopMail(){    
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("To Email");

        var SupplierVals = ss.getRange("H2:H").getValues(); //Supplier Column
        var Supplierlast = SupplierVals.filter(String).length;
        var supplierArray = bulk.getRange(2, 8,Supplierlast,1).getDisplayValues(); // unique supplier column

        var EmailVals = ss.getRange("J2:J").getValues(); //Email Column
        var EmailLast = EmailVals.filter(String).length;
        var emailArray = bulk.getRange(2, 10,Supplierlast,1).getDisplayValues(); // unique email column

      for each (var supplier in supplierArray ){
       for each (var emailAddress in emailArray ){
        var subject = "New Order";
        var emailBody = emailBody;
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject  + supplier,emailBody, {name: 'My Company', replyTo: 'orders@mycompany.com', to: emailAddress, htmlBody: emailBody});        
        var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Order has been sent to  ' + supplier + ' (' + emailAddress + ')', Browser.Buttons.OK); 
    }} 
}
```

Comment: [`for each (var in)` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in). Use a more appropriate iteration or enumeration syntax, **especially** for `Array`s. I recommend you use the `Array#filter` method to restrict the inner array to only those for the given supplier.

Comment: You want to send mails using the email address when "Supplier Name" is the same between the active sheet and "To Email" sheet. If my understanding is correct, it is required to retrieve the values of "Supplier Name" from both sheets to compare the name. But in your script, only one column is retrieved. And I'm not sure about ``emailBody``. In order to understand correctly your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information from it. I think that such information will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Thank you ver much guys. I will try your code and if I don't manage will post a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

A Support function.  I used a modeless dialog for helping to debug the code.

```
function colHeight(col){
  var col=col || 1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=vA.length-1;i>-1;i--){
    if(!vA[i][0]){
      vA.splice(i,1);
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

Here's the main function:

```
function emailVendorOrders(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  var erg=sh.getRange(2,5,colHeight(5)-1,2);
  var eA=erg.getValues();
  var emailObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<eA.length;i++){
    emailObj[eA[i][0]]=eA[i][1];
  }
  var orderObj={};
  var org=sh.getRange(2,1,colHeight(1)-1,3);
  var oA=org.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<oA.length;i++){
    if(orderObj.hasOwnProperty(oA[i][0])){
      orderObj[oA[i][0]].push({Item:oA[i][1],Qty:oA[i][2]});
    }else{
      orderObj[oA[i][0]]=[];
      orderObj[oA[i][0]].push({Item:oA[i][1],Qty:oA[i][2]});
    }
  }
  var hl='';
  for(key in orderObj){
    s='';
    s1='';
    s+=Utilities.formatString('Supplier: %s<br />',key);
    s1+=Utilities.formatString('Supplier: %s\n',key)
    s+=Utilities.formatString('Email Address: %s<br />',emailObj[key]);
    s1+=Utilities.formatString('Email Address: %s\n',emailObj[key]);
    for(var i=0;i<orderObj[key].length;i++){
      s+=Utilities.formatString('Item: %s Qty: %s<br />',orderObj[key][i].Item,orderObj[key][i].Qty);
      s1+=Utilities.formatString('Item: %s Qty: %s\n',orderObj[key][i].Item,orderObj[key][i].Qty);
    }
    s+='<br />';
    s1+='\n';
    var subject='New Order';
    //MailApp.sendEmail(emailObj[key[,subject  + key,s1, {name: 'My Company', replyTo: 'orders@mycompany.com', to: emailObj[key], htmlBody: s});
    hl+=s;
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(hl);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'title');
}
```

Here's what my spreadsheet looks like. My ranges are a bit different that yours.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I hinted in my comment, you can do this using two `Array` methods, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The idea is to read in the associated sheet range values for the orders and the suppliers:

```
const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const orders = wb.getSheetByName("Orders").getDataRange().getValues();
const suppliers = wb.getSheetByName("Suppliers").getDataRange().getValues();
```

Then, do some operation on each supplier and their associated data. Here is use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) Array method to construct a single plaintext message from the supplier's orders.

```
const supplierNameIndex = 0; // example - name in col A
const orderSupplierIndex = 3; // example - supplier name in col D
suppliers.forEach(function (supplier) {
  var name = supplier[supplierNameIndex];
  var supplierOrders = orders.filter(function (order) { return order[orderSupplierIndex] === name; });
  // Log data to Stackdriver for debug purposes
  console.log({message: "All orders for " + name, orderData: supplierOrders});

  // Do something with the filtered orders
  var preface = name + "\n\nPlease order the following:\n\n\tName\tSKU\tQuantity\n";
  var bodyText = supplierOrders.reduce(function (text, order) {
    text += "\t" + order[0] + "\t" + order[1] + "\t" + order[2] + "\n";
    return text;
  }, preface);
  bodyText += "\nThanks,\nShift Supervisor Steve";
  console.log({message: "Email text", text: bodyText});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing my code too much the following worked for me, placed within the for each loop

```
  //get email address of supplier - ie the value to the right of supplier column
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,8,10,2); // Column H:J
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == supplier) {
        var emailAddress = values[i][j+1];
        Logger.log("Email Address: " +emailAddress);
      }
    }    
  }  //END get email address of supplier - ie the value to the right of supplier column
```